# MVC4 Form Serialize to controller not working

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

I have tried just about everything to send a form back to my controller with ajax.

I have simplified my model to just strings.

- The ajax is pulling all the form data correctly.
- I have serilaizeArray() as well.

My object called model is null every time (the other parameters map just fine i.e. page, sort...). 
What am I missing?

Ajax:

```
...
var model = $('#advancesearchform').serialize();
var request = $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/DAM/Home/_ImageSearchResult",
    cache: false,
    traditional: true,
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: JSON.stringify({
        page: page,
        itemsperpage: itemsperpage,
        sort: sort,
        sortdir: sortdir,
        model: model
    }),
    success: function (data) {
        $('#imagesearchresults').html(data);
    }
});
```

The JSON.stringfy :
{\"page\":null,\"itemsperpage\":8,\"sort\":\"Project\",\"sortdir\":\"ASC\",\"model\":\"FileName=123&OriginalFileName=sas&Height=asas&Width=asas&DepartmentId=9b4463cd-c184-e211-9244-005056887208&ClassId=28de9d15-c284-e211-9244-005056887208\"}

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public PartialViewResult _ImageSearchResult(int? page, int itemsperpage, string sort, string sortdir, AdvanceSearchFilters model)
{
}
```

Model:

```
public class AdvanceSearchFilters
{
    public string FileName { get; set; }
    public string OriginalFormat { get; set; }
    public string Width { get; set; }
    public string Height { get; set; }
    public string MediaSource { get; set; }
    public string DepartmentId { get; set; }
    public string ClassId { get; set; }
    public string ThemeId { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problems is that you are sending data in the incorrect format. 
When you call $('#advancesearchform').serialize(); the data is formatted as a query string, but you are telling ajax to send JSON. With this:

```
{
 "page":null,
 "itemsperpage":8,
 "sort":"Project",
 "sortdir":"ASC",
 "model":"FileName=123&OriginalFileName=sas&Height=asas&Width=asas&DepartmentId=9b4463cd-    c184-e211-9244-005056887208&ClassId=28de9d15-c284-e211-9244-005056887208"
}
```

You are sending "model" as a string. What you need to do is either convert your advancesearchform atributes to a json format and attach them to  the current JSON or send everything as a query string.

For the first one, a quick soulution would be

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "/DAM/Home/_ImageSearchResult",
  cache: false,
  traditional: true,
  contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
  dataType: 'json',
  data: JSON.stringify({
    page: page,
    itemsperpage: itemsperpage,
    sort: sort,
    sortdir: sortdir,
    model: {
        FileName: $("#FileName").val(),
        OriginalFormat: $("#OriginalFormat").val()
        and so on...
```

for the second one, you could do something like

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "/DAM/Home/_ImageSearchResult",
  data: $('#advancesearchform').serialize() + "&page=" + page + "&itemsperpage=" + itemsperpage + "&sort=" + sort + "&sortdir=" +sortdir
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code the `AdvanceSearchFilters` class has a property called `OriginalFormat` whereas the serialize form has a value of **OriginalFileName**

Also I would recommend starting with an non ajax approach. If you can postback the values correctly in a non js environment then you know the problem is ajax related.

If the name value on the elements are incorrect then the model binder cannot map them correctly.  e.g. `AdvanceSearchFilters.Height` as apposed to `Height`

Comment: I already know it ajax related issue. I can do a post and it mapps fine. I need to do a ajax post so that I can pull the partial view on return. 
On your other point the binding should just skip the name that doesn't exist and write the others.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, try to look here : [JSON.Stringify examples](http://jsfiddle.net/ifandelse/6Yj5h/) 
Alternatively you can use $("form").serialize() to get your data serialized.

```
$.ajax({ 
url: "....",
method: "POST",
data: $("form").serialize()
})
```